# DeviceIoRequest to get STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR for USB storage fails

Tags: winapi, storage, ioctl

I am trying to get the `STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR` for storage devices by querying `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY` IOCTL with a properly filled out `STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY` struct. This works fine for non-USB storage, but for USB storage, this fails with `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`.

I also checked if that property exists by setting `QueryType` to `PropertyExistsQuery` and not providing an output buffer. Turns out, it exists. I don't see why it would fail with `ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION`.

Here is a cut-down version of the code I used (no error handling, etc):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <SetupAPI.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    HDEVINFO diskClassDevs;
    diskClassDevs = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK,
                                        NULL,
                                        NULL,
                                        DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);
    DWORD devIdx = 0;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA devInterfaceData;
    devInterfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(devInterfaceData);
    while(SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(diskClassDevs,
                                      NULL,
                                      &GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISK,
                                      devIdx,
                                      &devInterfaceData)){
        devIdx++;

        DWORD requiredSize;
        DWORD result = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(diskClassDevs,
                                                       &devInterfaceData,
                                                       NULL,
                                                       0,
                                                       &requiredSize,
                                                       0);
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA *devInterfaceDetailData;
        devInterfaceDetailData = malloc(requiredSize);
        devInterfaceDetailData->cbSize = sizeof(*devInterfaceDetailData);
        SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfoData;
        devInfoData.cbSize = sizeof(devInfoData);
        result = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(diskClassDevs,
                                                 &devInterfaceData,
                                                 devInterfaceDetailData,
                                                 requiredSize,
                                                 NULL,
                                                 &devInfoData);

        HANDLE devHandle;
        devHandle = CreateFile(devInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath,
                               GENERIC_READ,
                               FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                               NULL,
                               OPEN_EXISTING,
                               0,
                               NULL);

        STORAGE_DESCRIPTOR_HEADER diskDescriptorSizeInfo;
        diskDescriptorSizeInfo.Version = sizeof(diskDescriptorSizeInfo);

        STORAGE_PROPERTY_QUERY diskProperty;
        diskProperty.QueryType = PropertyStandardQuery;
        diskProperty.PropertyId = StorageDeviceProperty;
        result = DeviceIoControl(devHandle,
                                 IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
                                 &diskProperty,
                                 sizeof(diskProperty),
                                 &diskDescriptorSizeInfo,
                                 sizeof(diskDescriptorSizeInfo),
                                 &requiredSize,
                                 NULL);

        STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR *diskDescriptor;
        diskDescriptor = malloc(diskDescriptorSizeInfo.Size);

        diskDescriptor->Version = diskDescriptorSizeInfo.Size;
        result = DeviceIoControl(devHandle,
                                 IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
                                 &diskProperty,
                                 sizeof(diskProperty),
                                 diskDescriptor,
                                 diskDescriptorSizeInfo.Size,
                                 &requiredSize,
                                 NULL);

        printf("Bus Type: %s\n", (diskDescriptor->BusType == 7 ? "USB" : "not USB"));

        //GET STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR HERE
        diskProperty.PropertyId = StorageAccessAlignmentProperty;
        STORAGE_ACCESS_ALIGNMENT_DESCRIPTOR diskAlignment;
        diskAlignment.Version = sizeof(diskAlignment);
        result = DeviceIoControl(devHandle,
                                 IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY,
                                 &diskProperty,
                                 sizeof(diskProperty),
                                 &diskAlignment,
                                 sizeof(diskAlignment),
                                 &requiredSize,
                                 NULL);
        if(!result){
            printf("IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY failed (Error: %lu)\n", GetLastError());
        }else{
            printf("Physical sector size: %lu\n", diskAlignment.BytesPerPhysicalSector);
        }
        printf("----------------\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: simply some devices can not implement this property and return `STATUS_INVALID_DEVICE_REQUEST`. look how this handled [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/storage/class/classpnp/src/class.c#L8440) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/storage/class/classpnp/src/utils.c#L1694). for `PropertyExistsQuery` usually always [ok returned](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/storage/class/classpnp/src/utils.c#L1741) - this query not informative

Comment: I see, thanks. What is the reason that for *PropertyExists* usually *ok* is returned, no matter if the property can be queried?

Comment: but i paste you link to implementation - https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/storage/class/classpnp/src/utils.c#L1737 - for `if (query->QueryType == PropertyExistsQuery) ` always `status = STATUS_SUCCESS;   goto Exit;`, for other query types - `if (query->QueryType != PropertyStandardQuery)` - error returned `status = STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED;
        goto Exit;` and for `PropertyStandardQuery` depend from port driver